# How to set the location of the intermediate directory in knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I redirect the output of my `Rmd` rendering to another folder via `output_dir`. This creates the intermediate folder `<input name>_files` in the **output directory** but I do not want to have the `_files` folder to be there. Ideally I would not like to have it in the first place but reading [Chapter 16.5 in the RMarkdown Cookbok](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/keep-files.html) it is a feature and not a bug that the intermediate folder `_files` is not deleted for self containing files as soon as we have a chunk with `cache = TRUE`.

I tried to set the intermediate folder via `intermediates_dir` but to no avail, the `_files` folder will always be in the output folder.

What can I do to

1. Not have this folder (without setting `cache = FALSE`)?
2. And if this is not possible, move the `_files` folder at least to another place?

### Reprex

1. Create an `RStudio` project and create folders `tmp` and `docs` under the project root.
2. Press the `knit` button or Press `Ctrl+Shift+K` for the following file named `test.Rmd`:

   ````
   ---
   title: "Test"
   knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, 
                        intermediates_dir = here::here("tmp"),
                        output_dir = here::here("docs"))
      })
   ---

   ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
   ```

   ## R Markdown

   ```{r cars, cache = TRUE}
   summary(cars)
   ```

   ## Including Plots

   ```{r pressure, echo = FALSE}
   plot(pressure)
   ```
   ````
3. You will see now that a folder `test_files` appear under `docs` and not under `tmp`

Comment: We can make an another solution. 1. Output .pdf file +  2. folder with images etc + 3. inter folder with images and md file. If you are interested in this answer, i can add.

Comment: @manro definiely. I am outputting to HTML but his should not be a dealbreaker, right?

Comment: I think, no. I'll try a little later. And add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This is your example:**

````
---
title: "Test"

---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r cars, cache = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

```{r pressure, cache = TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

**I rendered via console, easier to experiment :)**

```
library (rmarkdown)

render(input = "our_file.Rmd",
       output_file = "our_file.html", #we should add an extention of the first output_format or this file will be rewritten
       output_format = c("html_document", "pdf_document"),
       intermediates_dir = "tmp",
       clean = FALSE
)
```

What will we achieve in the working directory:

1. two output files;
2. tmp folder with .md file and two folders with content(html/pdf);
3. folders with cache and content separately.

---

**An addition:**

I thought, that we can remove the folder_files:

```
unlink("folder_files", recursive = TRUE)
```

... and we can.

But this package don't create **every time (maybe only in the first process???**) and our knitting process falls.

I tried to find out, **where is a problem.**

If you open **.md file**, you will see:

```
![](C:/MyFolder/folder_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf)<!-- -->
```

... yes, it takes content from that folder or from output_dir...

How to redirect to tmp or another folder, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, but what I want is that the content folder is not created. Or at least not created in the output dir.

Comment: @thothal Look to an addition